# How to use guess-language package

Tags: python

I am trying to detect the language of a string, and have decided to use `guess-language`. However, there is not documentation or examples on how to use it. Does anyone know how I would use this package to detect the language of a given string?

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/guess-language

For example, something like:

```
>>> from guesslanguage import detect_language
>>> detect_language('Hello this is Bob')
English
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> from guess_language import guessLanguage
>>> guessLanguage('ボウリング・フォー・コロンバイン(字幕版)')
'ja'
```

Comment: Is there something better than this? It could detect that "today was a good day" is English >>> guessLanguage('la vita e bella')
'UNKNOWN'
>>> guessLanguage('today is a good day')
'UNKNOWN'

Comment: @MonaJalal yea it's lousy. Try Google Translate, send it the string and see if it can detect the language. That's much better.

Comment: @MonaJalal, its quirky, it needs >= 20 characters to make a language determination.

Answer (score 1):

See the [README](https://bitbucket.org/spirit/guess_language) on guess_language over at bitbucket. The site provides support for python 3 as well

Comment: It's a pity that the README doesn't document the use of hints. I have a case e.g. where I know upfront that the text will be either English or Latin, so I can improve the accuracy by calling `guess_language("some text here", hints=['la','en'])`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this instead:

```
from langdetect import detect
lang = detect("Hi, How are you doin?")
>>> print lang
>>> 'en'
```